# React Native - Hide floating menu View after touching outside of it

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to do this sort of simple pop-up menu. I need to make it hide when the user taps outside of it as you would expect. How can I detect if the user taps outside the menu so I can hide it?

```
class MainScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    /*code...*/  

    this.state = {
        menuVisible: false
    }
}
render () {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>                                
            <View style={[styles.headerContainer]}> 
                /*This is the Menu Button*/
               <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.setState({ menuVisible: !this.state.menuVisible })} style={[styles.menuButton]}>
               </TouchableHighlight>                       
            </View>  

            <View style={[styles.labelContainer]}>                     
                /*irrelevant code here...*/
            </View> 
            /*Render the floating menu if the Menu Button has been tapped*/
            {this.state.menuVisible ? this.FloatingMenu() : null}     
        </View> 
    )
}
```

This is the method that returns the Floating Menu:

```
/*Floating/Pop-up menu*/
FloatingMenu(){                 
    return(
        <View style={[styles.floatingMenu]}>
             <TouchableHighlight onPress={option1Handler}>
                   <Text>Menu option 1</Text>
             </TouchableHighlight>
             <TouchableHighlight onPress={option2Handler}>
                   <Text>Menu option 2</Text>
             </TouchableHighlight>
             <TouchableHighlight onPress={option3Handler}>
                   <Text>Menu option 3</Text>
             </TouchableHighlight>                 
        </View>
    )                   
}
```

...and these are the styles:

```
container: { 
  flex: 1      
},      
headerContainer: { 
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: 'row',
  alignItems: 'stretch',
  justifyContent: 'space-between'
},
labelContainer: { 
  flex: 7,
  alignItems: 'center'
},
floatingMenu: {
  position: 'absolute',
  right: 5,
  top: 5,
  opacity: 1,
  borderRadius: 2,
  padding: 5
}
```

I tried using the `onStartShouldSetResponderCapture` property on the other View containers like this `<View style={[styles.labelContainer]} onStartShouldSetResponderCapture={this.setState({ menuVisible: false });}>` in order to hide the menu and that works but I would have to add that to all the containers so that doesn't seem like the proper way to do it